# Custom fields (wp_post_meta) vs Custom Table for large amount of data

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, query-posts, post-meta, advanced-custom-fields

This is already a common question but I didn't find an answer for my specific problem on my research, so here it is.

I have a Custom Post Type that needs about 100 fields of data (these fields may be used or not, it depends on the data), from text, numbers and images. From those 100 fields I will need to query at max 10 fields for searching a ordering purposes. As the website grows, the post count will rise for the thousands and tens of thousand posts...

Now the question is what should I use? Custom fields(via plugin or not) or a Custom Table for all the data I need for my post type?

I'm familiar with the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin, it's good because it's easy to use but ACF is a bit of a mess in the databaes... as it doubles the amount of fields just because the way it works and for this amount of data I need I don't think it's the best solution.

Apart from my first question, is there a Custom Fields Plugin that maybe handle this differently? or my solution is a custom table?

Thank you in advance.